# Jackson JSON Deserialization - How to assign object members based on JSON values?

Tags: java, json, jackson, json-deserialization

I have some ugly JSON that I need to deserialize which looks like the following:

```
"ContainerValues": [
                        {
                          "ParentAttribute": "QuantityContained",
                          "RowList": [
                            {
                              "Values": [
                                {
                                  "Name": "Code",
                                  "ValuesByLocale": {
                                    "en-US": "GRM"
                                  },
                                },
                                {
                                  "Name": "Value",
                                  "ValuesByLocale": {
                                    "en-US": "4.0"
                                  },
                                }
                              ],
                             
                            }
                          ],
                        }
                      ],
```

This is just a sample of the JSON I have. All I need to do is to get this into a POJO which looks like something like the following:

```
Class POJO{
    String grmValue; // This is the "Value" for the GRM "Code" above, i.e. "4.0"
    ...
}
```

Any idea how I might be able to assign the value of grmValue based on the JSON above using Jackson? I'm starting to think I'll need to write a custom deserializer.

Comment: I would use standard Jackson deserializer and than transform regular POJO into one you expect.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to deserialize the data to a class similar to your JSON format, then transform it to your POJO format.